# Median value from table with number:count format

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, qubole

Given a table

```
+------------+-----------+
 |  Number   |  Count    |
+------------+-----------+
 |  0        |  7        |
+------------+-----------+
 |  1        |  1        |
+------------+-----------+
 |  2        |  3        |
+------------+-----------+
 |  4        |  1        |
+------------+-----------+
```

Which is representing such a number sequence: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4

find the median number, in this case it's 0, with sql. You will need to run this query in hive (qubole)

Thoughts?

Comment: @Drew, can you point to the question this is a duplicate of?  I searched but could not find one.  This isn't a standard median calculation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fairly straightforward solution in Hive.  You'll need this [UDF](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect/NumericRange.java) here.  Essentially, you want to un-aggregate your count data and then percentile it.

**Query**:

```
add jar /path/to/jar/brickhouse-0.7.1.jar;
create temporary function numeric_range as 'brickhouse.udf.collect.NumericRange';

select percentile(number, 0.50) median
from (
  select number
  from db.table
  lateral view numeric_range(count) n1 as n) x
```

The inner query will produce

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
2
2
2
4
```

Then you can just use the `percentile()` function on this column

**Output**:

```
median
------
0.0
```